# grunt uglify can't find my files in parent directory

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Unlike all of the other node projects i've written, this one needs the node server's folder to not be root. Here's the current folder hierarchy:

```
- Root/
  - build/
  - css/
  - im/
  - js/
  - nodeserver/   <-- gruntfile and package are here
```

`GruntFile.js`, `package.json`, and `server.js` are all located in `nodeserver/`

Here is my GruntFile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            files: {
                '../build/all.min.js':['../js/config.js']
            },
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
                report: true
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

When I run grunt, it can't find the file that I'm specifying. This is the response:

```
Running "uglify:files" (uglify) task
------------------------------------
Verifying property uglify.files exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: banner="/*! demo-webservice 2014-03-28 */\n", footer="", compress={"warnings":false}, mangle={}, beautify=false, report
```

Why can't it see my js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `files: {}` in `my_target: {}` solved my problem.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: {
                '../build/all.min.js':['../js/config.js']
            }
        },
        options: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
            report: true
        }
    }
});
```

^--- the new version of that initConfig.

It should also be noted that `my_target` could be anything, and is used by default since it is the only uglify profile supplied. If i had supplied more than one profile, i.e. "test: {}, prod: {}, etc: {}", then I would refer to them after the task in the following way: `uglify:test`, `uglify:prod`, `uglify:etc`